# Product Count Per Category in Magento

Tags: product

I have this web site with the main menu (drop down effect) on my frontpage/homepage. In the main menu I have 7 different categories for my products. All categories are linked to category's pages, and that is absolutely OK.

I would like it to show how many products are in the specific category (number of total items in category, right beside the link).

for eample:
Shirts **(10)**

Comment: define which theme u can use?

Answer (score 2):

> Display product count in top menu see hear

Magento categories marked as 'Include in menu' are added by  **page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before** 
event observer function addCatalogToTopmenuItems located in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Observer.php to 

app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Observer.php
```

[Lets overwrite it:](http://www.goivvy.com/blog/display-product-count-in-top-menu)

[image]

[**Only for subcategory menu on top**](http://istockphp.com/magento/get-product-count-in-top-menu-subcategories/)

[image]

Comment: Ravi thanks for effort. I'm not using default menu and theme, it is custom made theme, i just need to display product count for specific category (lets say id category is 4).

Comment: more idea to go for category code. base\default\template\catalog\navigation\left.phtml

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to this.

Bellow is a code which is working in my case:

```
<?php 
$products_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4)
->getProductCount();
echo($products_count);
?>
```

where "4" is the id of the wanted category.

thanks to Ravi Patel for his effort one more time.

Comment: it working thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can get category product count by below code

```
<?php 

$categoryId = 'YOUR_CATEGORY_ID';
$products_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getProductCount();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($catid);

/**
 * looping through sub categories
 * only showing active sub categories ($cat->getIsActive())
 */
foreach($collection as $cat) {
    if($cat->getIsActive()) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getEntityId());

        $prodCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addCategoryFilter($category);

        ?>

        <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a> (<?php echo $prodCollection->count() ?>)<br/>

        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

OUTPUT:-

1. New Arrivals (14)
2. Tops & Blouses (21)
3. Pants & Denim (8)
4. Dresses & Skirts (22)